# Only 1 place_id for every marker

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm filtering nearby places around the user and i want to get the place_id of every marker/place around the user.

but then it only shows 1 place_id for all marker/place. The logcat shows the different place_id but it the application, It's only snippet 1 place_id.

For the deeper understanding: i posted a sample video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0pmjblb_G8.

As you can see, Every time I try to click on the marker/place, it shows up the same place_id with the other marker/place.

I can post any other needed codes for clarification.

> UPDATE: additional info:

I made the placeId as a **static string placeId.**
then i added this on the MainActivity

```
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(traffic.this, " " + GetNearbyPlacesData.placeId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
```

So that i can see the placeId of each marker/place.

> UPDATE: additional info:

```
public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    String googlePlacesData;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    String url;
  static  String placeID = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
            mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
            url = (String) params[1];
            DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
            googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
        }
        return googlePlacesData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList = dataParser.parse(result);
        ShowNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList, result);
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");

    }


    private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList, String result) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("onPostExecute", "Entered into showing locations");

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
            String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //CHECK IF i IS CHANGING HERE
                //CHECK IF RESULTS AND PLACE ID ARE CHANGING WITH DEBUGGER
                placeID = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id");
                Log.d("onPostExecute", placeID);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                        .snippet("placeId:" + placeID)
                        .title("placeId:" + placeID));
                m.showInfoWindow();
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }



//            markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);



            //move map camera


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place ID comes back in the JSON response of the Places API nearby search.

You can see there something like:

```
 ...
 "results":[
{
  "geometry":{
    "location":{
      "lat":-33.8688197,"lng":151.2092955
    },
    "viewport":{
      "northeast":{
        "lat":-33.5782519,"lng":151.3429976
      },
      "southwest":{
        "lat":-34.118328,"lng":150.5209286
      }
    }
  },
  "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
  "id":"044785c67d3ee62545861361f8173af6c02f4fae",
  "name":"Sydney",
  "photos":[
    {
      "height":2448,
      "html_attributions":[
        "Hatim Ghadhban Abood"
      ],
      "photo_reference":"CoQBdwAAAMIVPsN50AxLsKj-QiQ2pCrKaXTZd-OpHHcQ4BrHkrFYylWZS1MP0GDqAA8GrZIsqvgg97eDsQVV7UPGeGnIvRTJHPPbnkOmW6VhoxKXAKX_0NqCYAiK4twz4a4ELPwPC0tyCeU1KtkYcKknhhgohG41F4JbFru4m0NiFE3TtAp_EhC1wpA1LN68NZOJ1l_iXctoGhTNz_68e8x-dPM6G0PAZiWezSkvsg",
      "width":3264
    }
  ],
  "place_id":"ChIJP3Sa8ziYEmsRUKgyFmh9AQM",
  "reference":"CmRbAAAA5LVfsLJXuBE1N7KDgJUTSgHHbGpGUVGgnLPVkobaylk6n9MsiPlqlYMmC0AdkqgzITScK_qDs05-n3ut6RMcrT2rHRwN36_pI8RoPNbNe9fPbOIyO2kTX9o7svURRqTpEhB4Phdre1afknnC5Ex2AewpGhRNNL5e4kxo1_L4BJgGZrRZlmWnmQ",
  "scope":"GOOGLE",
  "types":[
    "colloquial_area","locality","political"
  ],
  "vicinity":"Sydney"
},...
```

There is a field `place_id` that you need to extract. If you follow the mentioned tutorial you can see that you parse the JSON response in [DataParser](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/DataParser.txt) class, so you have to modify the `private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson)` method to add place ID to the place HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson) {
    HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String placeName = "-NA-";
    String vicinity = "-NA-";
    String latitude = "";
    String longitude = "";
    String reference = "";
    String placeID = "";

    Log.d("getPlace", "Entered");

    try {
        if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
            placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");
        }
        if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
            vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
        }
        latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
        longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
        reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");
        //Let's get place ID here
        placeID = googlePlaceJson.getString("place_id");

        googlePlaceMap.put("place_name", placeName);
        googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity", vicinity);
        googlePlaceMap.put("lat", latitude);
        googlePlaceMap.put("lng", longitude);
        googlePlaceMap.put("reference", reference);
        //Let's add place ID to hash map
        googlePlaceMap.put("place_id", placeID);

        Log.d("getPlace", "Putting Places");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("getPlace", "Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return googlePlaceMap;
}
```

After that you will be able to retrieve a place ID in your async task that shows markers (look at `ShowNearbyPlaces` method):

```
public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

String googlePlacesData;
GoogleMap mMap;
String url;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
        mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
        url = (String) params[1];
        DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
    }
    return googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
    DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
    nearbyPlacesList =  dataParser.parse(result);
    ShowNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
    Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
}

private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute","Entered into showing locations");
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");

        //Retrieve a place ID here
        String placeID = googlePlace.get("place_id");

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the place_id of each marker is always the same. what i mean is: i put a snippet in a marker like this:                     markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.travel_agency)).snippet("placeId:"+ placeID ); everytime i click a marker in the map, there's a place_id that is showing but not for that specific marker/place, it showing a place_id that is wrong.

Comment: I'm using onMarkerClick then i will toast the place_id, i tried to click all marker in the map and the toast keep showing the same place_id over and over again.

Comment: I believe, you should post your code, otherwise we don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Codes is posted in the link above, I just added a onMarkerclick and a toast.